# Log4J Appender UDP

Tags: sockets, udp, log4j

I need to use log4j to append logs to a socket with UDP.  However, I cannot find much on the internet about how to do so. In Log4J, the socketappender uses TCP.  So I got log4j 2 beta, but I can't find any examples/documentation on how to use the socketappender, especially for UDP.  I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me an example/show me how to use Log4j for UDP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with log4j 2.0-beta8 and got the UDP appender working with following  log4j2.xml file (but note the 2 in the name of the file!):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appenders> 
          <Socket name="UDP" host="myhostname.com" port="3333" protocol="UDP">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
       </Socket>
       </appenders>
       <loggers>
           <root level="info">
               <appender-ref ref="UDP"/>
           </root>
       </loggers>
    </configuration>
```